# Rotating IplImage creating distorted image using OpenCV

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv, iplimage

I am having difficulty when I am trying to live stream from android device to RTMP. First it was streaming good however, it was tilted so got a code to rotate the image.

```
 public  IplImage rotateImage(IplImage img) {
        IplImage img_rotate = IplImage.create(img.height(), img.width(),
                img.depth(), img.nChannels());
        //acctually, I don't know how to use these two methods properly
        cvTranspose(img, img_rotate);
        cvFlip(img_rotate, img_rotate, 1);   //?????90?

        return img_rotate;
    }
```

My code where I call the rotate from onPreviewFrame():

```
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
         videoTimestamp = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

         // Put the camera preview frame right into the yuvIplimage object
         yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);
        try {

             // Get the correct time
                recorder.setTimestamp(videoTimestamp);

                // Record the image into FFmpegFrameRecorder
                recorder.record(rotateImage(yuvIplimage));

            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

As a result of this, I am getting the below image

[image: Rotated Image however distorted]

In some other post, I came to know that we have to use

```
    rgbimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(yuvimage, rgbimage, opencv_imgproc.CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);
```

Then we can rotate however when ever I use this, I get exception BufferOverflow sometimes and sometimes RuntimeException

Comment: I recommend upgrading to OpenCV2.0 or 3.0 since most of the cvXXX functions just convert IplImage* structures to Mat objects (no deep copies). The api's you are using are old one.

Comment: @Rahul..I have no idea how to implement the new jar cause the class are changed now. Can you please provide me code to get started?

Comment: You should use cvTranspose() or cv::transpose() because  it's more efficient. Again, I recommend upgrading to OpenCV2.0 since most of the cvXXX functions just convert IplImage* structures to Mat objects (no deep copies). If you stored the image in a Mat object, Mat.t() would return the transpose.

Any rotation:
You should use cvWarpAffine by defining the rotation matrix in the general framework of the transformation matrix. With 2.0/3.0 you can use warpAffine to the above. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

Comment: can you give me code for cvTranspose

Comment: it is there in the link i mentioned in above comment

Comment: okay i will look into it!!..Thanks anyway!!!